# How to implement this by RegularExpression

Tags: perl

```
my $s1 = 'a1a2a3a4a5';
my $pat = '(a\d(?=a\d)a\d)';
while($s1 =~ m/$pat/g)
{
   print "$1\n"
}
```

I want to get output:

```
a1a2a3
a2a3a4
a3a4a5
```

But output is:

```
a1a2
a3a4
```

By my knowledge, next match in loop is started from ?=, but by my practice, it is not work in this way. Who can point out the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .... next match in loop is started from ?=

The next match within `//g` is started where the last match left off. A `(?=...)` does not magically set the position where the next match will start; it simply checks if the part inside `(?=...)` would match at the current position without advancing the position.

If your regex would be `/(a\d(?=a\d))/` then the match would be done after the first `a\d` although it makes sure that there is a second `a\d` behind it. But your regex is `/(a\d(?=a\d)a\d)/` which means simplified regarding the match `/a\da\d/`, i.e. it is done after the second `a\d`.

What you could do to achieve what you want is for example the following:

```
my $s1 = 'a1a2a3a4a5';
while($s1 =~ m/(a\d(?=(a\da\d)))/g)
{
   print "$1$2\n"
}
```

This will put the first `a\d` into `$1`, capture the second `a\da\d` into `$2` but still finish the match after the first `a\d`. Only you need to print `"$1$2"` then instead of only `"$1"`.

Comment: By my understand, (?=pat1)pat2 only take a look whether there is a pat1 at current matching position but do not match it to move current matching position. Then continue to match pat2 at current match position and then advance the position. Right?

Comment: @user2799433: right: the `(?=pat1)` only looks if the pattern exists but does not move the end of the match. But the `pat2` then actually matches and also moves the end of the match. Since you essentially used the same pattern for `pat1` and `pat2` (i.e. `(?=pat)pat`) the positive lookahead  `(?=pat)` was essentially irrelevant since it was followed by exactly the same pattern with a "real" match, i.e. the lookahead and the real match started and ended at the same position.